# CDS SQLite boolean comparison no longer working

Tags: sqlite, boolean, sapui5, cds, cap

We have a SAP CAP backend in Nodejs with a SQLite database. This is only for development purposes, in production it runs a HANA database.

After upgrading to version 7.5.3 of the @sap/cds package, the boolean comparison all of the sudden no longer works.

So I have a database table Projects, that includes two boolean values: isExample and isArchived. In the Projects page (SAPUI5 frontend) we filter projects based on these two values:

```
this.filters = [
   new Filter('isExample', FilterOperator.EQ, false),
   new Filter('isArchived', FilterOperator.EQ, false)
];
```

`this.filters` is used as `filters` object in the databinding.

Since the update I no longer receive any data from the database with these filters enabled. The same occurs when adding these filters directly into a view in the schema:

```
entity ProjectsArchive as projection on Projects where Projects.isArchived = true
entity ProjectsExamples as projection on Projects where Projects.isArchived = false and ProjectsSearch.isExample = true
```

Whenever I disable the filters, it works and I receive data. On production, with the HANA database, this just works without any issues.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I tried to change the 'true/false' values to '0/1' values, or 'true' and 'false' as strings. This all did nothing.

I reviewed the actual view on the database:

```
SELECT [list-with-columns]
FROM MainService_ProjectsSearch AS ProjectsSearch_0
WHERE ProjectsSearch_0.isArchived = TRUE
```

In the DB Browser for SQLite this returns 0 items. When I change the WHERE to `.isArchived = 'TRUE'`, it works and the query returns values. But in code that does not make a difference.

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug report?